# Google Dataflow vs Apache Spark Streaming (either on Google Cloud or with Google Dataproc)

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I am new to Cloud and Big-data however have much of interest in these and I have significant experience in Java programming. I am currently working on my uni project for comparing performance of Apache Spark streaming with Google Cloud Dataflow. I have read a number of articles including the comparison done [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/blog/dataflow-beam-and-spark-comparison).

I understand that the programming model of Spark and Dataflow is different, however because of my limited and new knowledge in this area, I am trying to understand if this performance comparison can still be done?
and what type of use case would be correct for this? And what performance parameters should be considered here for a streaming application?

While reading about Dataflow and Spark, I also came across Dataproc and also thinking if it is better to do comparison between Dataflow vs Spark on Dataproc or Dataflow vs Spark+Google Cloud.

Any advise on this would be appreciated as I am not getting a clear direction in this.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to compare performance is with real end-to-end data processing pipelines. So you first need to answer your own question "what type of use case would be correct for this?" as there are a nearly unlimited variety.

You might find some inspiration in the [included examples](https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/tree/master/examples/java).